# how to properly write a sum

Tags: summation, mathematical-modeling

What is the correct way to write a sum? I want to write a general formulation for the voltage at the last node of a line of an electrical grid. Here is an example line:

[image]

I have written:

\begin{equation}
u_\mathrm{last}=u_0-\sum_{l\in\mathcal{L}}\Big(Z_l\cdot\sum_{\substack{n\in\mathcal{N}\\n\geq l}}I_n\Big)
\end{equation}

where $\mathcal{L}=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ is the set of lines  and $\mathcal{N}=\{1, 2, 3 , 4\}$ is the set of nodes. $Z_l$ is the impedance of the $l$-th line and $I_n$ is the current into the $n$-th node (attached loads, that are not depicted in the picture). $u_0$ is the voltage at the transformer low voltage side. So for example the last voltage node of a line with 3 nodes would be:

$$
u_3=u_0-\big(Z_1\cdot(I_1+I_2+I_3)+Z_2\cdot(I_2+I_3)+Z_3\cdot I_3 \big)
$$

Is my general formulation above correct? Because my Professor (he is not a mathematician, just like me) thinks, that sum operators allways need upper and lower bounds, like:

$$
\sum_{l_0}^{l_n}
$$

But with these upper and lower bounds, Im not sure how to properly express, that the sum of $I$ is getting one element shorter each iteration of the outer sum.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: When you start with $n=0$ then the upper limit should be $N-1$, otherwise $n=1$ to $n=N$.

Comment: Try doing it for a simpler chain, then generalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are usually more than one way to represent a sum and your approach is fine. In fact considering $3$ nodes with *index* sets
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{N}=\{1,2,3\}=\mathcal{L}
\end{align*}
together with a special node $u_0$ we have the equality chain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{u_3}&=u_0-\left(Z_1\cdot(I_1+I_2+I_3)+Z_2\cdot(I_2+I_3)+Z_3\cdot I_3 \right)\\
&\color{blue}{=u_0-\sum_{l\in\mathcal{L}}Z_l \sum_{\substack{n\in\mathcal{N}\\n\geq l}}I_n}
\color{blue}{=u_0-\sum_{l=1}^3Z_l\sum_{n=l}^3 I_n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

- As we can see at the left-hand side of (1), lower and upper bound need not be explicitly stated. They are nevertheless implicitly given by definition of $\mathcal{N},\mathcal{L}$ and the constraint $n\geq l$.
- Another aspect is, that $l\in\mathcal{L}$ does not imply any *order* of summation. We just have to take each element from $\mathcal{L}$ in any order we like. This is admissible since addition is commutative.

*Hint:* You might find chapter 2: *Sums* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik helpful. It provides a thorough introduction in the usage of sums.